# How to apply disabled attribute on div tag which is a formgroupname in angular 4

Tags: html, angular

Code snippet:

```
<div formGroupName="address" [disabled] = "isDisabled">
<label class="accordion-header">Address:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="address" value="true" formControlName="address" [checked]="settingsForm.controls.address.controls.booleanAddress.value === 'true'">Inherit
  <input type="radio" name="address" value="false" formControlName="address" [checked]="settingsForm.controls.adddress.controls.booleanAddress.value === 'false'">Override
```

Im not able to use disabled or readonly on formgroupname at div or section tags. I can apply at formcontrol name in component class, but the requirement is to apply disable at group level.

How do I disable the whole group?

I'm using Angular 4.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no way to disable div; however you can simulate this using CSS `pointer-events:none`

You can do like below :

```
<div formGroupName="address" [ngClass]="{'disableDiv': isDisabled}">
<label class="accordion-header">Address:</label>
  <input type="radio" name="address" value="true" formControlName="address" [checked]="settingsForm.controls.address.controls.booleanAddress.value === 'true'">Inherit
  <input type="radio" name="address" value="false" formControlName="address" [checked]="settingsForm.controls.adddress.controls.booleanAddress.value === 'false'">Override
```

and in SCSS :

```
.disableDiv{
    pointer-events:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I will definately try that.

Comment: works a treat. I also added background-color grey and opacity:0.4 to lay a mask over the div.

Answer (score 1):

this is the way I disable all the elements:

```
<fieldset  [attr.disabled]="true">
</fieldset >
```

instead of using div you need to add `fieldset`. sometimes you even can find this like that:

```
<fieldset ng-disabled="true"> 
</fieldset >
```

but for me the `[attr.disabled]="true"` worked well.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot, without writing some kind of custom directive. Neither `readonly` not `disabled` attributes are valid for `div` tag in HTML.

Comment: Yeah I heard that ,But I'm new to angular .So could you please show me how I could achieve that?